# XAML DataGrid Column Borders

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 21 columns where the first column contains a date and the other twenty are monetary values, i.e. the number must be formatted right aligned with 2 decimal digits. Logically always three, three and one columns belong together so what I want to achieve is that grid lines are invisible but every third column should have a vertical border on the right side.

Any hint how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define all columns explicitly in your XAML markup and define a CellStyle for every third column that sets the BorderBrush and BorderThickness of the DataGridCell. Something like this:

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding First}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Second}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Third}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0" />
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you mm8. Works perfect! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the default style (In my case MaterialDesign Style) define a style:

```
   <Style
            x:Key="MyDataGridCell"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridCell}"
            TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        </Style>
```

Then apply the style to the DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid  CellStyle="{StaticResource MyDataGridCell}"
        GridLinesVisibility="None"  >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn
                        x:Name="Column1"
                        MinWidth="120"
                        Binding="{Binding Status}"
                        CanUserResize="False" /></DataGrid>
```